# Know the state of a SQL Server job execution

Tags: sql-server, ansible

I'm trying to launch a bunch of jobs from Ansible (using osql):

```
- name: 'Starting jobs'
        win_shell: 'osql -S {{ server }} -Q "exec msdb.dbo.sp_start_job {{ item }}" -U {{ username }} -P {{ password }}'
        args:
          executable: cmd
        with_items: '{{ jobs }}'
        until: jobs_out.stdout.find("started successfully") != -1
        register: jobs_out
```

Everything works fine but I don't have information about the current state of the job execution. I don't know if it's running or already finished.

Is there any way to have somekind of PID or block osql until it finished? Is there any Ansible module for doing this?

Any sugestion are welcome, but I cannot touch the jobs

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure if that answers your question. The [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/win_shell_module.html#notes) states that:

> WinRM will not return from a command execution until all child processes created have exited. Thus, it is not possible to use win_shell to spawn long-running child or background processes. Consider creating a Windows service for managing background processes.

So as long as the Ansible task is running the `osql` command is also running. If you want to prevent `osql` commands to run on the host that functionality would need to be part of the `osql` command.

If you are looking for real-time log output of the command, that is not implemented in Ansible and is not going to [be](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/3887#issuecomment-54672569)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but does not answer my question. The problem is that osql finish because the job execution is a backend process. So Ansible finish almost immediately

Comment: Ah ok. a) `osql` seems to be deprecated, use [sqlcmd](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility). You probably need to figure out some condition and create a [wait_for task](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/wait_for_module.html).